# Float the span element inside the td

Tags: html, css, less

How can I set the span element float towards the right of the `td` element in the HTML?

[image]

In the above image, I need to place the text `1` (small letter) floating towards the **right** of the column. Inside the column, there is already an input field that exists.

I have tried out different ways to set through the CSS but didn't work.

I want to make that text `1` always aligned right to the input field like superscript and maintain the position in the responsive template.

Code:

```html
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>House</td>
       <td>
         <span class="position-absolute badge-tooltip">
               1
         </span>
         <input class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 m-0 d-block text-right" type="text" />
       </td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

CSS

```css
.badge-tooltip {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post code

Comment: Show your code. I didn't understand what you really want to do but have you tried the text-align CSS property? with the value of right? I can' tell if that would work or not without seeing the code.

Comment: @Yuniac I have added the code for reference

Comment: The float works fine. It is canceled by something else, that you have not included in the code you posted - probably you use an absolute position. Instead, align your element to the top/right/whatever and maybe use padding to adjust how it is displayed in the table cell.

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the bootstrap class `position-absolute`, so to achieve the effect you want, instead of using `float:right`, add the bootstrap class `position-reletive` to the parent element and `top-0 end-0` to the child element:

```
   <td class="position-relative">
     <span class="position-absolute top-0 end-0">
           1
     </span>
     <input class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 m-0 d-block text-right" type="text" />
   </td>
```

This will align the span to the top-right like a superscript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your own position absolute, like this.

Just bear in mind that the `right` value needs to be adjusted based on if the next `td`s elements have any text in them and on different resolutions it needs to be changed using `media-queries or you can set the value with` %` percentage, which is responsive in nature but you have to fiddle with it to figure out the right percentage.

```css
    .relative-td {
      position: relative;
    }

    .position-absolute {
      position: absolute;
      right: -15px;
      bottom: 3px;
    }
```

```html
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td>House</td>
           <td class="relative-td">
             <span class="position-absolute badge-tooltip">
                   1
             </span>
             <input class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 m-0 d-block text-right" type="text" />
           </td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: This only works if he wants all his items to flow from right to left. He seems to only want one item to float right. Also, I think the attribute "position-absolute" , which he hasn't posted, ruins it anyway.

Comment: Yes @Gowiser, I don't want all the items to be aligned to the right. Just the span item. ```position-absolute``` is the class from bootstrap to position it.

Comment: I see now, I have edited my answer, I hope it helps now.

Comment: @Yuniac It works with some minor tuning. Thanks for your help